# How to include external libraries with my QGIS plugin?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis

I'm developing a plugin which makes use of "**networkx**" library extensively. However, networkx is not part of Python libraries pre-installed in QGIS.

Is there a way to include this library with my plugin installation, so that my plugin can be portable?

Comment: I think this is a good question. Have you considered opening a bounty to get more attention?

Comment: Very similar question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80272/distribute-qgis-plugin-which-depends-on-certain-python-packages