# Distributing PyQGIS Plugin Locally with External Modules

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyinstaller

I'm developing plugin with QGIS (3.4)'s in built python3 and plugin builder, I've also installed external python modules like opencv, PIL. The plugin will be used and stay in the company only.

Can we just copy the working folder (generated by pb_tool contains code and ui) with installed additional python packages, and ask the user to use plugin loader to load?

I've read [Distributing QGIS plugin which depends on certain Python packages](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80272/distribute-qgis-plugin-which-depends-on-certain-python-packages/183739) but my preference is end user's convenience, I don't want them to use pip install their own, and my plugin package size is not a problem.